# Can I make Dolphin more robust to file system issues?

Tags: kde, dolphin

Using Ubuntu 22.04 with Plasma (5.24.7 on X11).  I have an NSF mount served by another computer (Ubuntu 20.04) and mounted by this computer that, on a good day, works fine.  Sometimes, however, it doesn't work fine.  I understand NSF can be finicky, and that's not the issue here.

The issue is that any issue with this NSF mount causes my file explorer (Dolphin) to freeze up and become completely useless, permanently.

If I open a new instance of Dolphin, it opens in the default location of my home folder.  The NSF mount is to a folder `/etc/data/`, and it has *nothing* to do with my home folder.  However, if there's any issue at all with the NSF mount, all of Dolphin breaks, regardless of where it is in the filesystem.

Having opened to my home folder, I find that if I mouse over the folders shown in the listing, they highlight weakly in the normal way.  If I click on any folder, it highlights strongly in the normal way, and then Dolphin freezes.  Neither right-clicking nor left-clicking have any effect on any element of the UI except for the very top bar.  There, I can successfully minimize Dolphin with the "minimize" icon, but when I re-expand it from the taskbar the outline reappears but the contents do not fill in.

I can also select the "close" icon, in which case Dolphin will wait a moment before raising an error modal

> Application "dolphin" is not responding
>
> You tried to close window "Home -- Dolphin" from application "dolphin" (Process ID: 61006) but the application is not responding.
>
> Do you want to terminate this application?

It isn't a case of Dolphin needing extra time to deal with the NSF mount, either.  I've opened Dolphin, attempted to move to a folder within my home folder, had it freeze, and left it there for many hours.  Nothing changes.  Dolphin simply becomes unusable until I reboot.

When this happens, navigating the filesystem via the terminal is no problem at all.  Obviously I can't move into the NSF mount, but everything else is perfectly normal.  The problem is clearly Dolphin itself.

It seems unreasonable to me that my file explorer should completely shit the bed because of a routine error in a portion of my file system that I'm not even asking it to load.  Is there anything I can do to stop this?